# Not able to play mp4 files

Tags: video, mp4, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I am not able to play mp4 files even though I've installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, I'm getting the following error: `The specified movie could not be found`

Details:
Ubuntu Version: `20.04`
File Location: `/home/zayaan/Videos/Screencasts - mp4`
File Name: `Screencast from 29-07-23 05_34_07 PM IST.mp4`

Errors:
When I run with the videos app, I get the following error:

```
xxxxxx@xxxxxx-Inspiron-3584:~/Videos/Screencasts - mp4$ totem "Screencast from 29-07-23 05_34_07 PM IST.mp4"

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.095: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.115: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.137: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.158: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.177: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.191: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.226: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.308: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.326: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.344: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.360: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:47.377: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 19:59:48.739: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.318: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.451: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.467: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.480: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.498: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.516: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.533: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.550: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.568: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.585: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.603: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.621: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.638: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.655: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed

(totem:107422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:00:00.798: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed
```

Comment: "...could not be found" is not something to do with codecs. Where is that mp4 file? Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You should add information such as the version of Ubuntu and what app you tried to open an mp4 file.

Comment: @mikewhatever I've edited the question

Comment: Install VLC with `sudo apt install vlc` and try playing the file with VLC

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yeah, I've done that, but I still prefer the default video player and want to use it. VLC, just has an overall old-ish UI that doesn't really fit into the new modern operating systems' look and feel

Comment: Why did the question get closed!!?? What's wrong/missing in the question?

Comment: You can change VLC themes/skins. You need to run the movie in the video player from terminal and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1481315/edit) the question and post the full error message. The question will be eventually reopened (I did not vote to close it)

Comment: Your edited output shows that VLC does not have any issues playing the file (which does not help us solve the issue with the other media player). Open it with the other media player instead, which has the issue. The command is `totem "Screencast from 29-07-23 05_34_07 PM IST.mp4"`

Comment: try "rm -r ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/"

Comment: @petep The question already got answered by another question... And it said the same thing. It worked